# Determine which SNS topics a SQS queue is subscribed to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Is there a way to list all of the AWS SNS topics that a particular SQS queue is subscribed to, using the AWS CLI?

I already know how to see the list of subscribers on an SNS topic, but that only works if I know the name of the SNS topic. In this case, I only know the name of the SQS queue.

I wasn't able to find anything by [searching the interwebs](https://www.google.com/search?ei=VDexWtT4MI7v_Qbh-bmQCw&q=aws%20sqs%20list%20SNS%20subscriptions&oq=aws%20sqs%20list%20SNS%20subscriptions&gs_l=psy-ab.3...190147.194641.0.195330.12.12.0.0.0.0.175.1371.7j5.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.8usKJWezLyg).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such API for this purpose, so as a work around you can use SNS cli command `aws sns list-subscriptions` and filter by your SQS arn (using a `grep` command maybe). This approach may not be feasible depending on how many subscriptions exists on you account (results are paginated in a 100 items batch). You can filter subcriptions by topic to reduce results by using `list-subscriptions-by-topic`.

Comment: Problem is that you can't lookup what the cross account subscriptions are. I think it's completely insane that AWS has no way of finding the relations between a queue and a topic.

Comment: Confirmed. No cross account subscriptions are found, this is a pain.

Comment: I believe this is actually possible, please check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65007484/2267316.