# How to List which SNS topics a SQS queue is subscribed to using cli or boto3?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, boto3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I need to list all sns topic which is subscribed with sqs queue by using CLI or Python BOTO3, kindly share your idea or code, it will very helpfull for me.

Answer (score 5):

```
aws sns list-subscriptions --query 'Subscriptions[?Protocol==`sqs` && Endpoint==`arn:aws:sqs:<region-name>:<account-id>:<sqs-queue-name>`] | [0].TopicArn'
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply, but I need to list all topics and the subscribed sqs queue.

Comment: If you need to list them all, just remove the last bit ` | [0].TopicArn`.